# ADF Dataflow Debug

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

when I try turn on the debug mode for dataflows I immediately get this response.
[image]

I have tried to create a new integrated runtime and still it fails instantly. I have tried this on two different accounts. Is there an error log somewhere where I am able to see why it failed

Comment: This could be a transient issue. Could you please retry and see if the error persists?

In case if the error occurs again, please do share type of subscription and the ADF region?

Comment: I select East Us instead of auto resolve and it worked perfectly